# Paramiko sendcmd like in Python ftplib

Tags: ftp, sftp, paramiko, ftplib, hp-nonstop

I have a host system with two systems on it (HP Nonstop).
With Python ftplib I can use

```py
ftp = FTP()
ftp.encoding = encoding
ftp.connect(host_addr, ftp_port)
ftp.sendcmd('guardian')
```

to use the *Guardian* system paths (`$X.PATH.FILENAME`) or use

```py
ftp = FTP()
ftp.encoding = encoding
ftp.connect(host_addr, ftp_port)
ftp.sendcmd('oss')
```

to use the OSS system paths (unix like)

For SFTP I use Paramiko. But I cannot use the guardian paths because I cannot find a command like `sendcmd`.

```py
transport = paramiko.Transport((host_addr, ssh_port))
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

Answer (score 0):

SFTP protocol is binary. It is not a textual protocol like FTP. You cannot use SFTP to send proprietary textual commands to server. The server *might* implement a proprietary binary request. But that's not common.

You first have to find out what (if any) API does your SFTP server have to achieve the functionality of its FTP `oss` command. It won't be *anything like* `sendcmd` for sure. A common hack that some proprietary SFTP servers use is that you first need to attempt to access/list a virtual path with a command-like syntax that switches the server to the desired state.